# UIBarButton is not working for back action

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to set a back button to `UIBarButton`, but `IBAction` is not working properly. I am not sure what went wrong.
can any one let me know.

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    // Tell the controller to go back
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: print NSLog before beginning of this function or debug your code and check if this function is called. If no, check have you set IBAction properly to your button.

Comment: can you show us some of the code from previous controller where you are pushing this navigation controller?

Comment: Then you are not properly managing your navigation controller

Comment: Add code where you are pushing your view controller

Comment: @PradeepKumar: just four lines, how you have created object of this navigation controller, how you are pushing it, etc etc....

Comment: no ankur i did not created any navigation controller object on previous view controller, do i have too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your back Method with this :

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    // Tell the controller to go back
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope your problem is solved.

Enjoy ...!!!